# Find minimum and maximum key and value of an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

May someone help me to find the minimum and maximum key and value for each year?
I want for example to print "television-3" and "printer-1".
This is the code in php

```
$year = array (
"year 2015 " =>  array( 
    "Television" => "3",
    "phone"     => "4",
    "personal computer"=> "5",
    "printer"     => "5",
),
"year 2016 " =>  array( 
    "Television" => "3",
    "phone"     => "7",
    "personal computer"=> "4",
    "printer"     => "1",
)
);
```

Comment: what should be the maximum key/value for the first year?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it should be personal computer-5 and printer-5

Comment: I suppose, you don't compare the keys by some criteria, you're just want to get max/min value and their keys

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes exactly

Comment: @belka  is the keys include "year 2016" or you just want "Television"?

Comment: @KrisRoofe i  just need Television-3, but it would be great if i could post the year too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding min & max from array, php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829810/finding-min-max-from-array-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `array_map`, `array_intersect`, `min`, `max` and `asort` functions:

```
$result = array_map(function($y){
    $slice = array_intersect($y, [min($y), max($y)]);
    asort($slice);

    return $slice;    
}, $year);

// the min/max items are in ascending order (minimum values, then - maximun values)
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [year 2015 ] => Array
        (
            [Television] => 3
            [printer] => 5
            [personal computer] => 5
        )

    [year 2016 ] => Array
        (
            [printer] => 1
            [phone] => 7
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$year = array (
"year 2015 " =>  array( 
    "Television" => "3",
        "phone"     => "4",
            "personal computer"=> "5",
                "printer"     => "5",
                ),
                "year 2016 " =>  array( 
                    "Television" => "3",
                        "phone"     => "7",
                            "personal computer"=> "4",
                                "printer"     => "1",
                                ));
$result = []; 
foreach($year as $val)
{
    foreach($val as $k => $v) 
    {   
        $result[$k][] = $v; 
    }   
}
array_walk($result, function(&$v){
    $v = ['min' => min($v), 'max' => max($v) ];
});
var_dump($result);
```

output:

```
kris-roofe@krisroofe-Rev-station:~$ php cal.php 
array(4) {
  ["Television"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["min"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["max"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["phone"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["min"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["max"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  ["personal computer"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["min"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["max"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  ["printer"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["min"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["max"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the code you're looking for:

```
function find_min_max_products($year) {
    foreach($year as $key => $value) {
        $year_str = explode(' ', trim($key));
        $year_str = end($year_str);

        $products_with_min_qty = array_keys($value, min($value));
        $products_with_min_qty = array_flip($products_with_min_qty);
        $products_with_min_qty = array_fill_keys(array_keys($products_with_min_qty), min($value));

        $products_with_max_qty = array_keys($value, max($value));
        $products_with_max_qty = array_flip($products_with_max_qty);
        $products_with_max_qty = array_fill_keys(array_keys($products_with_max_qty), min($value));  

        $products[$year_str] = array(
            'min' => $products_with_min_qty,
            'max' => $products_with_max_qty
        );
    }

    return $products;
}

$year = array (
    "year 2015 " =>  array( 
        "Television" => "3",
        "phone"     => "4",
        "personal computer"=> "5",
        "printer"     => "5",
    ),
    "year 2016 " =>  array( 
        "Television" => "3",
        "phone"     => "7",
        "personal computer"=> "4",
        "printer"     => "1",
    )
);

$products = find_min_max_products($year);
var_dump($products);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [2015] => Array
        (
            [min] => Array
                (
                    [Television] => 3
                )

            [max] => Array
                (
                    [personal computer] => 3
                    [printer] => 3
                )

        )

    [2016] => Array
        (
            [min] => Array
                (
                    [printer] => 1
                )

            [max] => Array
                (
                    [phone] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Hope it helps!